# Jackson @JsonIgnore Annotation - Relationship Values Don't get Returned

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have a mysql db from which i have generated the TransferObject Using Hibernate. There is a one to many relationship beteween city and patients, city and doctors, specialty and doctors. However i don't get any returned values when querying the database from those one to many relationships.

When i test RestFul End Points i get:

/doctors/all

```
[{"id":1,"email":"papa@papa.com","fatherName":"πατέρας","firstName":"όνομα","lastName":"επίθετο","telephone":"2821074737"},{"id":2,"email":"lala@gmail.com","fatherName":"dfjs","firstName":"Ιωσήφ","lastName":"Βαρουξάκης","telephone":"8583848824"},{"id":3,"email":"","fatherName":"","firstName":"Χαράλαμπος","lastName":"Πρωτοπαπαδάκης","telephone":"4343454345"},{"id":4,"email":"","fatherName":"","firstName":"Ελευθέριος","lastName":"Παπαδάκης","telephone":"2821084834"},{"id":5,"email":"","fatherName":"","firstName":"Παναγιώτης","lastName":"Τζεράκης","telephone":"28210848383"},{"id":6,"email":"","fatherName":"","firstName":"Κων/νος","lastName":"Κωνσταντινίδης","telephone":"2821084838"},{"id":7,"email":"","fatherName":"","firstName":"Παναγιώτης","lastName":"Ψιστάκης","telephone":"2810838383"},{"id":8,"email":"","fatherName":"Εμμανουήλ","firstName":"Θεανώ","lastName":"Πατακάκη","telephone":"2821048438"},{"id":9,"email":"","fatherName":"","firstName":"Μαρία","lastName":"Καφούση","telephone":"2810848283"},{"id":10,"email":"","fatherName":"","firstName":"Μανούσος","lastName":"Χριστοδουλάκης","telephone":"2810848383"},{"id":11,"email":"saf@fdsa.gr","fatherName":"αφδσ","firstName":"φδσα","lastName":"σφδ","telephone":"2323233223"},{"id":12,"email":"","fatherName":"φεδσαφ","firstName":"φδσαφδσα","lastName":"φδσαφγσφαδ","telephone":"3333333333"},{"id":13,"email":"mixtou@gmail.co","fatherName":"Dimitrios","firstName":"Toutoudakis","lastName":"Mixail","telephone":"6948571893"}]
```

/patients/all

```
[{"id":1,"birthday":"1975-08-19","email":"mixtou@gmail.com","fatherName":"Δημήτριος","firstName":"Μιχαήλ","lastName":"Τουτουδάκης","telephone":"6948571893","sex":true},{"id":2,"birthday":"1942-06-10","email":"lla@gmail.com","fatherName":"Μιχαήλ","firstName":"Δημήτριος","lastName":"Τουτουδάκης","telephone":"7364927473","sex":true},{"id":3,"birthday":"1975-05-06","email":"lala@gmail.com","fatherName":"Μιχαήλ","firstName":"Μιχαήλ","lastName":"Μαραγκάκης","telephone":"8484848484","sex":false},{"id":4,"birthday":"1957-08-14","email":"lasdjf@lkdafs.gr","fatherName":"Τεστ","firstName":"Μηνάς","lastName":"Παπαδάκης","telephone":"8484842747","sex":false},{"id":5,"birthday":"2018-03-26","email":"","fatherName":"","firstName":"Στέφανος","lastName":"Μαριόλος","telephone":"4838583845","sex":true},{"id":6,"birthday":"2018-03-20","email":"jkdas@gjal.com","fatherName":"Μ..κας","firstName":"Κων/νος","lastName":"Μπλαζάκης","telephone":"2347878763","sex":false},{"id":7,"birthday":"2018-03-08","email":"ajs@gjla;.gr","fatherName":"pateras","firstName":"f;ldas","lastName":"akdfsj","telephone":"445354345453","sex":true},{"id":8,"birthday":"2018-03-12","email":"lala@gam.gr","fatherName":"Εμμανουήλ","firstName":"Ιωάννης","lastName":"Μαλανδράκης","telephone":"4343434343","sex":false},{"id":9,"birthday":"1980-05-12","email":"antonis@gmai.com","fatherName":"Δεν Ξέρω","firstName":"Αντώνιος","lastName":"Ιγγλεζάκης","telephone":"28210848484","sex":false},{"id":10,"birthday":"2018-04-19","email":"test@etes.gr","fatherName":"test","firstName":"test`","lastName":"tet","telephone":"2345674424","sex":false},{"id":11,"birthday":"1984-02-13","email":"lala@gmail.com","fatherName":"Δημήτριος","firstName":"Ιωάννης","lastName":"Μαλανδράκης","telephone":"1223323344","sex":false},{"id":12,"birthday":"2018-05-16","email":"lala@gmail.com","fatherName":"Τεεε","firstName":"Τέστης","lastName":"Τεστάκης","telephone":"84848484823","sex":false},{"id":13,"birthday":"2018-06-05","email":"lala@gmail.com","fatherName":"test","firstName":"test","lastName":"test","telephone":"2821022222","sex":true}]
```

/cities/all

```
[{"id":4,"name":"Αγ. Νικόλαος"},{"id":3,"name":"Ηράκλειο"},{"id":2,"name":"Ρέθυμνο"},{"id":5,"name":"Ρόδος"},{"id":1,"name":"Χανιά"}]
```

/specialties/all

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Αγγειοχειρουργική"},{"id":2,"name":"Αιματολογία"},{"id":3,"name":"Ακτινοδιαγνωστική"},{"id":4,"name":"Ακτινοθεραπευτική"},{"id":5,"name":"Αλλεργιολογία"},{"id":6,"name":"Αναισθησιολογία"},{"id":7,"name":"Γαστρεντερολογία"},{"id":8,"name":"Γενική Ιατρική"},{"id":9,"name":"Δερματολογία"},{"id":10,"name":"Ενδοκρινολογία"},{"id":12,"name":"Ιατρική Εργασίας"},{"id":13,"name":"Ιατροδικαστική"},{"id":14,"name":"Καρδιολογία"},{"id":15,"name":"Κυτταρολογία"},{"id":16,"name":"Μαιευτική Γυναικολογία"},{"id":11,"name":"Μικροβιολογία"},{"id":17,"name":"Νευρολογία"},{"id":18,"name":"Νευροχειρουργική"},{"id":19,"name":"Νεφρολογία"},{"id":20,"name":"Ορθοπαιδική"},{"id":21,"name":"Ουρολογία"},{"id":22,"name":"Οφθαλμολογία"},{"id":23,"name":"Παθολογία"},{"id":24,"name":"Παθολογική Ανατομική"},{"id":25,"name":"Παθολογική Ογκολογία"},{"id":26,"name":"Παιδιατρική"},{"id":27,"name":"Παιδοψυχιατρική"},{"id":28,"name":"Πλαστική Χειρουργική"},{"id":29,"name":"Πνευμονολογία - Φυματιολογία"},{"id":30,"name":"Πυρηνική Ιατρική"},{"id":31,"name":"Ρευματολογία"},{"id":39,"name":"Στοματική & Γναθοπροσωπική Χειρουργική"},{"id":32,"name":"Φυσική Ιατρική και Αποκατάσταση"},{"id":33,"name":"Χειρουργική"},{"id":36,"name":"Χειρουργική Β΄"},{"id":34,"name":"Χειρουργική Θώρακος"},{"id":35,"name":"Χειρουργική Παίδων"},{"id":37,"name":"Ψυχιατρική"},{"id":38,"name":"ΩΡΛ"}]
```

Everything works ok with one exception. The city and specialty relationship. I get no city or specialty data in replies.

Below is my implementation

My persistence.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnit">
        <!--<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>-->
        <class>gr.histopath.platform.model.TransferObjects.BodyPart</class>
        <class>gr.histopath.platform.model.TransferObjects.City</class>
        <class>gr.histopath.platform.model.TransferObjects.Clinic</class>
        <class>gr.histopath.platform.model.TransferObjects.Doctor</class>
        <class>gr.histopath.platform.model.TransferObjects.Incident</class>
        <class>gr.histopath.platform.model.TransferObjects.Patient</class>
<class>gr.histopath.platform.model.TransferObjects.SigningDoctor</class>        <class>gr.histopath.platform.model.TransferObjects.Specialty</class>
<class>gr.histopath.platform.model.TransferObjects.User</class>

        <properties>
            <!--<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>-->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/histopath.gr?useSSL=false&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=Europe/Athens"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="histopathUser"/>
            <!--<property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>-->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="h1s+0p@+h"/>
            <!--<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="Malak1es"/>-->
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="utf8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true"/>
            <property name="connection.pool_size" value="1"/>

            <!--<property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem"/>-->
            <!-- hibernate c3p0 connection pooling configuration  -->
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="60"/> <!-- seconds -->
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="0"/> <!-- seconds -->
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts" value="1"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay" value="250"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The Transfer Objects are:

City.java

```
package gr.histopath.platform.model.TransferObjects;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
public class City {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Collection<Doctor> doctors;
    private Collection<Patient> patients;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        City city = (City) o;
        return id == city.id &&
                Objects.equals(name, city.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(id, name);
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "city")
    @JsonIgnore
    public Collection<Doctor> getDoctors() {
        return doctors;
    }

    public void setDoctors(Collection<Doctor> doctorsById) {
        this.doctors = doctorsById;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "city")
    @JsonIgnore
    public Collection<Patient> getPatients() {
        return patients;
    }

    public void setPatients(Collection<Patient> patientsById) {
        this.patients = patientsById;
    }
}
```

Doctor.java

```
package gr.histopath.platform.model.TransferObjects;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
public class Doctor {
    private int id;
    private String email;
    private String fatherName;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String telephone;
    private City city;
    private Specialty specialty;
    private Collection<Incident> incidents;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "fatherName")
    public String getFatherName() {
        return fatherName;
    }

    public void setFatherName(String fatherName) {
        this.fatherName = fatherName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "telephone")
    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Doctor doctor = (Doctor) o;
        return id == doctor.id &&
                Objects.equals(email, doctor.email) &&
                Objects.equals(fatherName, doctor.fatherName) &&
                Objects.equals(firstName, doctor.firstName) &&
                Objects.equals(lastName, doctor.lastName) &&
                Objects.equals(telephone, doctor.telephone);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(id, email, fatherName, firstName, lastName, telephone, city, specialty);
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonIgnore
    public City getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(City cityByCityId) {
        this.city = cityByCityId;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "specialty_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonIgnore
    public Specialty getSpecialty() {
        return specialty;
    }

    public void setSpecialty(Specialty specialtyBySpecialtyId) {
        this.specialty = specialtyBySpecialtyId;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "doctor")
    @JsonIgnore
    public Collection<Incident> getIncidents() {
        return incidents;
    }

    public void setIncidents(Collection<Incident> incidentsById) {
        this.incidents = incidentsById;
    }
}
```

Patient.java

```
package gr.histopath.platform.model.TransferObjects;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
public class Patient {
    private int id;
    private Date birthday;
    private String email;
    private String fatherName;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String telephone;
    private Boolean sex;
    private Collection<Incident> incidents;
    private City city;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "birthday")
    public Date getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "fatherName")
    public String getFatherName() {
        return fatherName;
    }

    public void setFatherName(String fatherName) {
        this.fatherName = fatherName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "telephone")
    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "sex")
    public Boolean getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(Boolean sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Patient patient = (Patient) o;
        return id == patient.id &&
                Objects.equals(birthday, patient.birthday) &&
                Objects.equals(email, patient.email) &&
                Objects.equals(fatherName, patient.fatherName) &&
                Objects.equals(firstName, patient.firstName) &&
                Objects.equals(lastName, patient.lastName) &&
                Objects.equals(telephone, patient.telephone) &&
                Objects.equals(sex, patient.sex) &&
                Objects.equals(incidents, patient.incidents) &&
                Objects.equals(city, patient.city);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, birthday, email, fatherName, firstName, lastName, telephone, sex, incidents, city);
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient")
    @JsonIgnore
    public Collection<Incident> getIncidents() {
        return incidents;
    }

    public void setIncidents(Collection<Incident> incidentsById) {
        this.incidents = incidentsById;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public City getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(City cityByCityId) {
        this.city = cityByCityId;
    }
}
```

Specialty.java

```
package gr.histopath.platform.model.TransferObjects;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
public class Specialty {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Collection<Doctor> doctors;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Specialty specialty = (Specialty) o;
        return id == specialty.id &&
                Objects.equals(name, specialty.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(id, name);
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "specialty")
    @JsonIgnore
    public Collection<Doctor> getDoctors() {
        return doctors;
    }

    public void setDoctors(Collection<Doctor> doctorsById) {
        this.doctors = doctorsById;
    }
}
```

Any Ideas why values don't get returned?? Values exist in database, i can see them in mysql workbench or by simply querying the whole table. Do i forget to do something?? I think my error will be ridiculous

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by @JsonIgnore annotation. In my above example i have put it in both sides of the relationships (Both in @ManyToOne and @OneToMany). 
The problem was solved by removing it from @ManyToOne side and leaving it only at  @OneToMany side.

Comment: did you need to set optional=true?

Answer (score 0):

Good you solved your problem. I was reading your question and can't resist from commenting.

You should revisit your domain model (relationships). With current domain model, eventually you will face performance issue along with others.

If possible then remove one-to-many relationships between Specialty to Doctor; Patient to Incident; Doctor to Incident and City to Doctor, Patient.

Instead make Spcialty, Doctor, Patient and City as Master Entities (lifecycle won't depend on other entities. And keep following relationships:

- Doctor to Specialty: many to one
- Incident to Patient, Doctor: both many to one
- Doctor to City: many to one
- Patient to City: many to one

No one to many relationship is required.

Now if you want to fetch all the doctors in a city then do something like findAllByCity(City city).

When you create an Incident then you just need to pick Doctor and Patient and save the Incident. No need to cascade from Doctor and Patient side.

Final point: use secondary cache. It will share the performance burden with database.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you valuable comments. I will definitely follow your advice. However in every Hibernate Example I have seen, they implement the @ManyToOne and vice versa relationships the same way i did.

Comment: In those examples, they are just teaching the relationships but when you scale your application then you need to think about Entity-Relationship model along with other factors e.g. cache and model them accordingly. Otherwise it will affect your application. In any case, starting with one-to-many bidirectional relationship is not a blunder. If your application is performing well then its fine. Possibly you do some load testing to check your application's performance and then can decide. Anyway if you are just learning then forget my comment :P